# Code review of forward invocation

Tags: objective-c

Here's the situation. I'm writing a simple game and I had two main actors: `GameController` and `GridView`.

- `GridView` is a `UIView` subclass displaying a grid with which the user interacts. It defines its custom delegate protocol (`GridViewDelegate`) for handling callbacks such as `gridView:didSelectTile` and others.
- `GameController` is the game controller (duh!) which instantiate a `GridView` and set itself as a delegate, therefore implementing the `GridViewDelegate` protocol.

So far so good, then I decided to add HUD components on top of the grid (a score, a timer and other stuff). The most reasonable choice seemed to wrap such HUD components along with the grid into a new `UIView` subclass called `GameBoard`.

And here comes the design issue: I need the controller to talk to the `GridView` and I think there's two reasonable options here.

1. Expose a `gridView` property and do something like

   ```
   [self.gameBoard.gridView doStuff];
   ```
2. Forward the invocation made to `GameBoard` directly to `GridView` overriding the `forwardInvocation:` method of `GameBoard`

The first options looks like the most convenient, but I cannot get myself into liking it, due to the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

So I decided to go for the second approach and do something like

```
// The GameBoard serves a proxy between the GameContoller and the GridView
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    if ([self.gridView respondsToSelector:anInvocation.selector]) {
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:self.gridView];
    } else {
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
    }
}

// This method is necessary for the above forwardInvocation to work
- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    NSMethodSignature * signature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
    if (!signature) {
        signature = [self.gridView methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
    }
    return signature;
}
```

It works as expected, but I'd like to have a second opinion on my design choice.

I generally tend to avoid overusing of the dynamic features of Objective-C, but it looked like an elegant way to achieve my result fulfilling the Law of Demeter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you trying to overengineer solution a bit. First of all View should not do any stuff at all. View is just a View, sheet of paper. Maximum of view's responsibility is layouting himself. So controller should take care of other view-related stuff.

In this case I probably prefer to think about gridView as legitimate subview of GameBoard. I really doubt Demetra suffering when you doing something like `[self.view.titleLabel sizeToFit]`.

So my advice is to use `[self.gameBoard.gridView doStuff];` as simplest and straightforward solution.

Comment: By the way `forwardInvocation` will not be typechecked at all. Typesystem of Objective-C already too weak, don't make your life even harder. If you insist—I can advice to define `@protocol` for `GameBoard` with methods of `GridView`.